# How to define a series which has it's index in a countable set?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am wondering how is defined a series when it's index is in a countable set. So if $I$ is a countable set then how is $\sum \limits_{i \in I} a_i$ defined.

What i do know is that a regular series is defined as $\sum \limits_{n = 0}^{ + \infty} a_n = \lim \limits_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum \limits_{n = 0}^{N} a_n$ if the limit exists.

I also know that if $I$ is countable and for all $n$, $a_n$ is postive, $\sum \limits_{i \in I} a_i$ can be defined as $\sum \limits_{i \in I} a_i = \sup \limits_{\substack{J \subset I \\ J \text{ is finite}}} \sum \limits_{j \in J} a_j$ if the $\sup$ exists.

I know that this definition will not work if $a_n$ isn't always positive, my guess is that for $\sum \limits_{i \in I} a_i$ to exist, $\sum \limits_{i \in I} |a_i|$ must exist so that no matter the order in which we calculate this series the value will be the same.

Comment: Yes, if the series is not unconditionally (i.e. absolutely) convergent, then its value (if it exists) depends on the order of summation, so in that case the symbol $ \sum_{i\in I} $ is ambiguous.

Comment: For $I$ to be countable there must be a bijection $I \to \mathbb N$ and that leads to the usual sum.  If you want your series to have a unique finite sum over all such bijections then as you say it must converge absolutely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few years I have found 2 possible ways to define a series over an arbitrary set. For those that are asking themselves this same question I will share these definitions.

The first definition relying on measure theory would be for a set $I$ to consider the counting measure $n$ simply defined by $n(A) = Cardinal(A)$ and we can view the sequence $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ as a measurable function $a$ that goes from $I$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and simply define:
$$\underset{i \in I}{\sum} a_i = \underset{I}{\int} a(i) dn(i)$$

Another definition that is more elementary but which is equivalent (I think) is to define:
$$\underset{i \in I}{\sum} a_i = l \iff \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists F \in \mathcal{F}(I), \forall E \in \mathcal{F}(I), F \subset E \Rightarrow \left \lvert \underset{i \in E}{\sum} a_i  - l \right \rvert < \varepsilon$$
Where $\mathcal{F}(I)$ denotes the set of finite subsets of $I$, so $\underset{i \in E}{\sum} a_i$ is well defined because $E$ is finite.

But if I am not wrong, when we replace $I$ by $\mathbb{N}$ these definitions will only give us the absolutely convergent series which is not surprising since we do not take into account the order on $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $I$ is countable, there is a bijection from the natural numbers $f : \mathbb{N} \to I$. Then you can define
$$\sum_{i \in I} a_i = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{f(n)} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_{f(n)} \,.$$
As mentioned by Henry, this sum depends on the bijection $f$ (i.e. the order of summation) unless the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: There may be more than one such bijection

Comment: Ok thank you! So if I use this definition and request absolute convergence of the series I will have a rigorous and consistent definition right?

Comment: Yes: have a look at the Wikipedia article on absolute convergence, it is shown there that absolute convergence implies unconditional convergence (i.e. the sum is independent of the summation order).